# Can you use csv.DictReader without a file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I have some comma-separated input I want to parse into a dictionary, so `csv.DictReader` seemed like a good fit. However, the input is already in string form and not a file as the interface to `csv.DictReader` wants.

Is there a way to use `csv.DictReader` directly with a string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`StringIO`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html) (or [`io.BytesIO`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) / [`io.StringIO`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.StringIO)):

```
>>> import StringIO
>>> import csv
>>>
>>> f = StringIO.StringIO(u'''field1,field2,field3
... 1,2,3
... 4,5,6
... 7,8,9
... ''')
>>>
>>> for row in csv.DictReader(f):
...     print row
...
{'field2': '2', 'field3': '3', 'field1': '1'}
{'field2': '5', 'field3': '6', 'field1': '4'}
{'field2': '8', 'field3': '9', 'field1': '7'}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use any iterable producing lines, it doesn't just have to be a file object. You can split your string into a list of lines with [`str.splitlines()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines):

```
for row in csv.DictReader(inputtext.splitlines()):
    print row
```

Demo:

```
>>> import csv
>>> demostring = '''\
... foo,bar,baz
... 42,Monty,Python
... 38,Ham,Spam
... '''
>>> for row in csv.DictReader(demostring.splitlines()):
...     print row
... 
{'foo': '42', 'baz': 'Python', 'bar': 'Monty'}
{'foo': '38', 'baz': 'Spam', 'bar': 'Ham'}
```